# Subtype polymorphism in shapeless mapping

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've constructed the following:

```
import shapeless._
import poly._

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {

        object iterateOverHList extends (List ~> Iterator) {
            def apply[T](it: List[T]) = it.iterator
        }

        val x = List(1,2,3) :: List("cat","dog") :: HNil

        val xIt = x map iterateOverHList

    }
}
```

The above code works great and is awesome.  However, I still want more.  I would like to, rather than specifying that my HList will contain Lists, allow any Iterable.  Like this:

```
import shapeless._
import poly._

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {

        object iterateOverHList extends (Iterable ~> Iterator) {
            def apply[T](it: Iterable[T]) = it.iterator
        }

        val x = List(1,2,3) :: List("cat","dog") :: HNil

        val xIt = x map iterateOverHList

    }
}
```

This second version fails to compile, with the message "could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[iterateOverHList.type,shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.::[List[String],shapeless.HNil]]]".  The subtype polymorphism I'm expecting here, that a function that works on Iterable should work on List, is failing for some reason.  Why is that?  Is there a way for me to get around this problem, or will my own greed be my undoing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~>` works with exact types. If you want a `Poly1` for any subtype of `Iterable` you should create it like this:

```
object iterateOverHList extends Poly1 {
  implicit def iterable[T, L[T] <: Iterable[T]] = at[L[T]](_.iterator)
}
```

You could also create a `Poly1` that works on some types that could be treated as `Iterable` like this:

```
import scala.collection.generic.IsTraversableOnce
object iterateOverHList extends Poly1 {
  implicit def iterable[L](implicit i: IsTraversableOnce[L]) =
    at[L](i.conversion(_).toIterator)
}

val x = "abc" :: List(1,2,3) :: HNil
val xIt = x map iterateOverHList
// xIt: shapeless.::[Iterator[Char],shapeless.::[Iterator[Int],shapeless.HNil]] = non-empty iterator :: non-empty iterator :: HNil
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used the first one.  This solution caused a warning about enabling higher-kinded types, which was eliminated by importing scala.language.higherKinds.  I'm not sure I actually understand the solution, though.  I've seen "at" sprinkled throughout shapeless, but have been confused by it.  What does it do, and do you know where it's defined?

Comment: @jcrudy: `where at is defined and how it works` is a good SO question. And the answer is too big for comment. You should ask it as SO question (don't forget to mention `apply` method of `~>`). You could even get an answer from [Miles Sabin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/146737/miles-sabin).

Comment: @senia: How would the first solution work if type T must be bounded, e.g. iterable[T <: MyTrait, L[T] <: Iterable[T]]? It appears that it is shadowed by L[T] and the bound doesn't apply.

Comment: @senia Hmm, turns out my problem is having to do with using a custom type as the upper bound for L[T]. Started a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853858/shapeless-mapping-and-subtype-polymorphism-with-custom-type-bound