# What is "at" in shapeless (scala)?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've seen an object (probably a function) called "at" sprinkled throughout the shapeless source and in code that uses shapeless.  In particular, it is used in the answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894593/subtype-polymorphism-in-shapeless-mapping/20894753#20894753).  Here is the code snippet:

```
object iterateOverHList extends Poly1 {
  implicit def iterable[T, L[T] <: Iterable[T]] = at[L[T]](_.iterator)
}
```

I've had some clue that it is related to the apply method of the ~> type.  What specifically does "at" do, and where is it defined?

Comment: In theory this is the subject matter of part three of my blog series on polymorphic function values ... one day I might even get around to writing it ;-) While you're waiting @senia's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Definition of `PolyN#at`

`at` is a general way to work with `Poly`.

`~>` with `apply` is a [special case](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/dddf09f9d37aa29cbee90ef93c7fb57c0eed25af/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/poly.scala#L141) of `Poly1`. `apply` here is used to define implicit method using `at`:

```
implicit def caseUniv[T] = at[F[T]](apply(_))
```

Method `at` is [defined](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/a0d1aae67c659cdcae9b2e1cf77108ebdebabb74/project/Boilerplate.scala#L319) in `PolyN` (for instance in `Poly1`) like this:

```
trait PolyN extends Poly { outer =>
  type Case[T1, T2, ..., TN] = poly.Case[this.type, T1 :: T2 :: ... :: TN :: HNil]
  object Case {
    type Aux[T1, T2, ..., TN, Result0] = poly.Case[outer.type, T1 :: T2 :: ... :: TN :: HNil] { type Result = Result0 }
  }

  class CaseBuilder[T1, T2, ..., TN] {
    def apply[Res](fn: (T1, T2, ..., TN) => Res) = new Case[T1, T2, ..., TN] {
      type Result = Res
      val value = (l: T1 :: T2 :: ... :: TN :: HNil) => l match {
        case a1 :: a2 :: ... :: aN :: HNil => fn(a1, a2, ..., aN)
      }
    }
  }

  def at[T1, T2, ..., TN] = new CaseBuilder[T1, T2, ..., TN]
}
```

In case of `Poly1`:

```
trait Poly1 extends Poly { outer =>
  type Case[T1] = poly.Case[this.type, T1 :: HNil]
  object Case {
    type Aux[T1, Result0] = poly.Case[outer.type, T1 :: HNil] { type Result = Result0 }
  }

  class CaseBuilder[T1] {
    def apply[Res](fn: (T1) => Res) = new Case[T1] {
      type Result = Res
      val value = (l: T1) => l match {
        case a1 :: HNil => fn(a1)
      }
    }
  }

  def at[T1] = new CaseBuilder[T1]
}
```

So `at[Int]` creates an instance of `CaseBuilder[Int]` and `at[Int].apply[String](_.toString)` or just `at[Int](_.toString)` (synax sugar for `apply` method call) creates an instance of `poly.Case[this.type, Int :: HNil]{ type Result = String }`.

So with `implicit def iterable[T, L[T] <: Iterable[T]] = at[L[T]](_.iterator)` you create an implicit method to create a `poly.Case[this.type, L[T] :: HNil]{ type Result = Iterator[T] }`.

This implicit method is used in `map` (and in some other polymorphic functions).

#### Implementation of `HList#map`

`map` is [defined](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/dddf09f9d37aa29cbee90ef93c7fb57c0eed25af/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L285) like this:

```
def map(f : Poly)(implicit mapper : Mapper[f.type, L]) : mapper.Out = mapper(l)
```

(`L` is the type of `HList`)

To create a `Mapper` compiler [looks](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/348b62334e7b812d8cc006ba41defd389efd061e/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L255) for `Case1[Fn, T]`.

For `map(f)` on `A :: B :: ... :: HNil` compiler have to find implicits for `Case1[f.type, A]`, `Case1[f.type, B]` and so on.

In case of `List[Int] :: HNil` the only implicit `Case1` needed is `Case1[f.type, List[Int]]`.

Note that `Case1` is [defined](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/a0d1aae67c659cdcae9b2e1cf77108ebdebabb74/project/Boilerplate.scala#L269) like this:

```
type Case1[Fn, T] = Case[Fn, T :: HNil]
```

So we have to find an implicit value for `Case[f.type, List[Int] :: HNil]`.

In case `f` is an `object` one of the places to search for implicits is `f` fields and methods. So compiler will find `Case` defined in `f`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a pro, so @miles-sabin and @travis-brown can give complete and more clear answer, but mb I can try too (it is not complete and doesnt show all formal issues):

1. `iterateOverHList` It is a polymorphic function, extends `Poly1`, and if u look implementations of this (`Poly1`) trait, you'll see that it takes as arguments only one object typed in your exmpl as `L[T]`;
2. Function `at` exactly means (look the implementation below): "in case of type `L[T]` apply function inside `at`; so in your exmpl method `iterator` of your object.
   so you can write different implicit functions which can be applied on different types,     it is useful when u walk through a `HList` (with a map for example) with different and difficult types.

The implementation of `Poly` traits and proof of my words above you can find for example here: http://xuwei-k.github.io/shapeless-sxr/shapeless-2.10-2.0.0-M1/polyntraits.scala.html
Here we see that `Poly1` trait is:

```
trait Poly1 extends Poly { outer =>
    type Case[A] = poly.Case[this.type, A :: HNil]
    object Case {
        type Aux[A, Result0] = poly.Case[outer.type, A :: HNil] { type Result = Result0 }
    }

    class CaseBuilder[A] {
        def apply[Res](fn: (A) => Res) = new Case[A] {
            type Result = Res
            val value = (l : A :: HNil) => l match { case a :: HNil => fn(a) }
        }
    }

    def at[A] = new CaseBuilder[A]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough one to find, as the `PolyN` classes in shapeless are auto-generated via [Boilerplate.scala](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala).

All except for `Poly0`, which you can see [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/poly.scala#L398)

In short... It's just a method on `Poly1`