# what is Case.Aux in shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am confused about the example shown in the shapeless feature overview.

```
object size extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](x => 1)
  implicit def caseString = at[String](_.length)
  implicit def caseTuple[T, U]
    (implicit st : Case.Aux[T, Int], su : Case.Aux[U, Int]) =
      at[(T, U)](t => size(t._1)+size(t._2))
}

scala> size(((23, "foo"), 13))
res7: Int = 5
```

1. what is the Case.Aux ?
2. why is parameterised type is Int not String
3. if size(((23, "foo", 123), 13)), how to define CaseTuple ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

More explanations about `PolyN` function you can find here: [What is "at" in shapeless (scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912679/what-is-at-in-shapeless-scala)

**1 & 2.** So let's rewrite this code to make it more clear:

```
object size extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](x => 1)
  implicit def caseString = at[String](_.length)
  implicit def caseTuple[T, U]
    (implicit st : Case.Aux[T, Int], su : Case.Aux[U, Int]) =
      at[(T, U)](t => st(t._1) + su(t._2))
}
```

`Case` type class provides us applying some poly function to some object with it's type.
http://xuwei-k.github.io/shapeless-sxr/shapeless-2.10-2.0.0-M1/shapeless/poly.scala.html#shapeless.PolyDefns;Case

Let's try to make some function:

```
def sizeF[F, S](t: (F, S)) = size(t)
```

It is impossible, without type class wich defines how to apply function:

```
def sizeF[F, S](t: (F, S))
(implicit cse: Case[size.type, (F, S) :: HNil]) = size(t)
```

`Case.Aux[T, U]` it is a shortcut for: `poly.Case[this.type, T :: HNil]{ type Result = U }`
`T` - it is an argument, `U` - the result type after application.

**3.** Let's modify function and make avalible application to `((23, "foo", 123), 13)`, we need to add function to work with triples:

```
object size extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](x => 1)
  implicit def caseString = at[String](_.length)
  implicit def caseTuple[T, U]
  (implicit st : Case.Aux[T, Int], su : Case.Aux[U, Int]) =
    at[(T, U)](t => size(t._1) + size(t._2))
  implicit def caseTriple[T, U, F]
  (implicit st : Case.Aux[T, Int], su : Case.Aux[U, Int], sf: Case.Aux[F, Int]) =
    at[(T, U, F)](t => size(t._1) + size(t._2) + size(t._3))
}

size(((23, "foo", 123), 13)) //> res0: Int = 6
```

As expected.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can I understand Case.Aux this way, because Tuple can have multiple types, it needs to delegate Case.Aux to get each type and then recursively get the value. I wonder is there other good usage for the Case.Aux (maybe not implicitliy)

Comment: @Cloudtech as you saw, it is useful only for application; in my example of function `sizeF` it is possible to use `Case.Aux` : `implicit cse: size.Case.Aux[(F, S), R]` (you need to add `R` as a type parameter). In `shapeless` every type-class have an `Aux`, mb for beauty (to redefine `Result` type is an ugly thing) :) To define the result type is very useful when you use several type-classes and need to apply them chainly(I mean smth like `tc1(tc2(tc3(object)))`