# Polymorphic functions with constant return type in Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Long story short, I'm trying to figure out how to define a function from a generic input to a single-typed output.

**The background:** This is a continuation of [Mapping over Shapeless record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375886/mapping-over-shapeless-record). After [Travis's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26384377/807674), I now have the following:

```
import shapeless._
import poly._
import syntax.singleton._
import record._

type QueryParams = Map[String, Seq[String]]

trait RequestParam[T] {
  def value: T

  /** Convert value back to a query parameter representation */
  def toQueryParams: Seq[(String, String)]

  /** Mark this parameter for auto-propagation in new URLs */
  def propagate: Boolean

  protected def queryStringPresent(qs: String, allParams: QueryParams): Boolean = allParams.get(qs).nonEmpty
}

type RequestParamBuilder[T] = QueryParams => RequestParam[T]

def booleanRequestParam(paramName: String, willPropagate: Boolean): RequestParamBuilder[Boolean] = { params =>
  new RequestParam[Boolean] {
    def propagate: Boolean = willPropagate
    def value: Boolean = queryStringPresent(paramName, params)
    def toQueryParams: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(paramName -> "true").filter(_ => value)
  }
}

def stringRequestParam(paramName: String, willPropagate: Boolean): RequestParamBuilder[Option[String]] = { params =>
  new RequestParam[Option[String]] {
    def propagate: Boolean = willPropagate
    def value: Option[String] = params.get(paramName).flatMap(_.headOption)
    def toQueryParams: Seq[(String, String)] = value.map(paramName -> _).toSeq
  }
}
```

In reality, the following would be a class constructor that takes this Map read from the query string as a parameter, but for simplicity's sake, I'm just defining a `val`:

```
val requestParams = Map("no_ads" -> Seq("true"), "edition" -> Seq("us"))

// In reality, there are many more possible parameters, but this is simplified
val options = ('adsDebug ->> booleanRequestParam("ads_debug", true)) ::
  ('hideAds ->> booleanRequestParam("no_ads", true)) ::
  ('edition ->> stringRequestParam("edition", false)) ::
  HNil

object bind extends FieldPoly {
  implicit def rpb[T, K](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K]): Case.Aux[
      FieldType[K, RequestParamBuilder[T]],
      FieldType[K, RequestParam[T]]
    ] = atField(witness)(_(requestParams))
}

// Create queryable option values record by binding the request parameters
val boundOptions = options.map(bind)
```

This lets me do:

```
boundOptions.get('hideAds).value // -> true
```

**The problem:** Now I want to be able to reserialize options that have `propagate = true`. So basically, I need to filter my `HList` on the `propagate` field of every member, which should always return a `Boolean`, and then have each parameter reserialize itself to a `Seq[(String, String)]`. I've tried the following:

```
object propagateFilter extends (RequestParam ~> Const[Boolean]) {
  override def apply[T](r: RequestParam[T]): Boolean = r.propagate
}   

object unbind extends (RequestParam ~> Const[Seq[(String, String)]]) {
  override def apply[T](r: RequestParam[T]): Seq[(String, String)] = r.toQueryParams
}

// Reserialize a query string for options that should be propagated
val propagatedParams = boundOptions.values.filter(propagateFilter).map(unbind).toList 
// (followed by conventional collections methods)
```

, but it doesn't like my functions. I got the following error:

```
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: shapeless.Const[T]
    (which expands to)  AnyRef{type λ[T] = T}
             override def apply[T](r: RequestParam[T]) = r.propagate
```

I believe I'm taking the wrong approach to a function that's supposed to have a polymorphic input but monomorphic output.

**Other failed attempts:**

```
object propagateFilter extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T](implicit st: Case.Aux[RequestParam[T], Boolean]) = at[RequestParam[T]](_.propagate)
}
```

and

```
def propagate[T](x: RequestParam[T]): Boolean = x.propagate
```

and

```
object propagateFilter extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default = at[RequestParam[_]](_.propagate)
}
```

and

```
object propagateFilter extends FieldPoly {
  implicit def rpb[T, K](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K]): Case.Aux[
    FieldType[K, RequestParam[T]],
    Boolean
    ] = atField(witness)(_.propagate)
}
```

None of which work, probably due to my own misunderstanding of what's going on.

Comment: I can take a look at this later if nobody beats me to it, but for now note that I've made a (fairly small) [update to my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26384377/334519).

Comment: I realized that part of my issue is probably the fact that even though everything in my `HList` happens to be a `RequestParam[T]`, they don't really share a supertype. I fixed this temporarily factoring out the common interface into a non-parametric trait. But I think the more idiomatic approach might be to use an implicit typeclass.