# Shapeless mapping and subtype polymorphism with custom type bound

Tags: scala, polymorphism, shapeless

Trying to map an HList of a custom polymorphic class I'm getting the dreaded "could not find implicit value for parameter mapper" error. A code sample:

```
import shapeless._

trait SubTrait
case class A() extends SubTrait
case class B() extends SubTrait

case class C[T <: SubTrait](x: T)

object TheMapper extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T <: SubTrait, L[T] <: C[T]] = at[L[T]](_.x)
}

val ab = C(A()) :: C(B()) :: HNil

println(ab.map(TheMapper))
```

This works fine if the bound for L[T] is e.g. Iterable (see [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894593/subtype-polymorphism-in-shapeless-mapping), solution, and comments). What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason the real error gets swallowed. If you compile this step by step in the REPL you'll get this error:

```
error: type arguments [T] do not conform to class C's type parameter bounds [T <: SubTrait]
         implicit def default[T <: SubTrait, L[T] <: C[T]] = at[L[T]](_.x)
                                                     ^
```

The problem is that the `T` in `L[T] <: C[T]` is not the same as the one in `T <: SubTrait`. It gets more readable if you rename it:

```
scala> object TheMapper extends Poly1 {
     |   implicit def default[T <: SubTrait, L[x] <: C[x]] = at[L[T]](_.x)
     | }
<console>:18: error: type arguments [x] do not conform to class C's type parameter bounds [T <: SubTrait]
         implicit def default[T <: SubTrait, L[x] <: C[x]] = at[L[T]](_.x)
                                                     ^
```

The solution is to put a bound on `x`.

```
scala> object TheMapper extends Poly1 {
     |   implicit def default[T <: SubTrait, L[x <: SubTrait] <: C[x]] = at[L[T]](_.x)
     | }
defined object TheMapper

scala> val ab = C(A()) :: C(B()) :: HNil
ab: shapeless.::[C[A],shapeless.::[C[B],shapeless.HNil]] = C(A()) :: C(B()) :: HNil

scala> println(ab.map(TheMapper))
A() :: B() :: HNil
```

Comment: Note that convention is to write local type variables lower case.

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain Oh, ok. I can't say I've seen that done consistently enough to assume it's the convention. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Using the REPL as a debugger, nice :) Thank you!